# Javascript Media Query no responding

Tags: javascript, css, web

So I am building a website, I have some custom menus that use HTML and JS. when the menu is open it is 25% of the screen:

```
function opensideNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
}
//Closes Right sidenav
function closesideNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

If i use

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1023px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
    function opensideNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "25%";
    }
    //Closes Right sidenav
    function closesideNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
} else {
     function opensideNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
    }
    //Closes Right sidenav
    function closesideNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
}
```

It will only open the menu on a smaller screen than 1023.... I have tried changing the min to max but still the same problem. Pls help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use CSS media queries for this? you can do:

```
function toggleNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle("open");
}
```

in your JavaScript which toggles the `open` class on and off, this needs to be attached to whatever it is you're clicking to toggle the menu.

Then in your CSS you can do:

```
#mySidenav {
   width: 0;
}

#mySidenav.open {
   width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1023px) {
    #mySidenav.open {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

So what this is doing is the function in the JS is toggling the `open` class on and off of the `mySidenav` element when clicked. By default the CSS is giving `mySidenav` a `width` of `0`, then overriding that when the `open` class is applied. This also looks at the width of the viewport and changes what the width being applied is based on that.

Note your open nav button would be something like:

```
<button onclick="toggleNav()">Menu</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `min-width`. `min-width` in the context of media queries means that it will be applied if the viewport is having a minimum `width` of the given value. However, you intend to query by the `width` of the device, so `min-width` and `max-width` are not really helpful for your purpose. You will need to use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`, respectively to query the `width` of the device instead of the width of the viewport.